# Caching algorithm for a web API client wrapper

Tags: python, algorithm, caching, asp.net-web-api, lru

I developed a [Python client library](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm), which is a client wrapper for a web API: a nice-to-have feature would be a local cache mechanism: this would save time and bandwidth when the library clients invoke the very same request on the web API at different times.

I have very few requirements

1. the cache shall be developed (no external libraries) and run Python 2.6/2.7 envs
2. the library shall provide a uniform interface, so that it is possible to use external cache mechanism (eg: memcached) wrappers, which will be dependency-injected
3. the cache should be thread-safe
4. the content to be cached will be the JSON payload of the web API responses.
5. data provided by the web API vary at different time rats: in example, the currently observed weather over a city may vary every hour, while 15 days weather forecast may vary every 5 days or so.

What is the most simple algorithm that can be used?

I was thinking about a LRU (Least Recently Used) algorithm but I guess that other alternatives can be assessed - I'm not expert about caches at all!

Comment: with python 3.2 there is an already built-in lru cache with decorator symantics ( see [lru_cache](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) )

Comment: Unfortunately the library is only supporting Python 2.6/2.7... but thanks anyway, I'll add it to the requirements :)

Comment: Most simple would be to just have an expire time for each cached entry. Why do you need *the most* simple? LRU is simple enough :)

Comment: Being absolutely dumb about caches, I guess that many others are possible ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just copy and adapt the source from lru_cache (see http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/functools.py).